# Android Studio Gradle Build insanely slow

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

So a branch was merged in at my work and now I'm getting too slow of build times.  The only new addition to the gradle file was these two dependencies :

```
testImplementation 'android.arch.paging:common:1.0.1'
implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1'
```

The spots in the build process that are slow are

:app:kaptDevDebugKotlin and :app:kaptGenerateStubsDevDebugKotlin that take ~15 minutes each.  The other product flavors experience the same build times as these so with four flavors it'll take me 2 hours to build whereas it's normally under 4 minutes.  This only happens to my machine and not my team mates and it will happen to me even with a fresh Android Studio 3.2 install.  If I go back to before the paging library was added I can build just fine.

Some of the debug logs that stand out and might be useful

> 17:08:15.283 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.client.ref] RMI
>   RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:17933,org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.LoopbackNetworkInterface$ClientLoopbackSocketFactory@580e1ef0]:
>   get connection 17:08:15.284 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI
>   RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:17933,org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.LoopbackNetworkInterface$ClientLoopbackSocketFactory@580e1ef0]:
>   create connection 17:08:15.287 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.loader] RMI
>   RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:17933,org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.LoopbackNetworkInterface$ClientLoopbackSocketFactory@580e1ef0]:
>   name = "java.rmi.dgc.Lease", codebase = "" 17:08:15.288 [DEBUG]
>   [sun.rmi.loader] RMI
>   RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:17933,org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.LoopbackNetworkInterface$ClientLoopbackSocketFactory@580e1ef0]:
>   name = "java.rmi.dgc.VMID", codebase = "" 17:08:15.290 [DEBUG]
>   [sun.rmi.loader] RMI
>   RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:17933,org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.LoopbackNetworkInterface$ClientLoopbackSocketFactory@580e1ef0]:
>   name = "[B", codebase = "" 17:08:15.290 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.loader] RMI
>   RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:17933,org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.LoopbackNetworkInterface$ClientLoopbackSocketFactory@580e1ef0]:
>   name = "java.rmi.server.UID", codebase = "" 17:08:15.291 [DEBUG]
>   [sun.rmi.client.ref] RMI
>   RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:17933,org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.LoopbackNetworkInterface$ClientLoopbackSocketFactory@580e1ef0]:
>   free connection (reuse = true) 17:08:15.291 [DEBUG]
>   [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI
>   RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:17933,org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.LoopbackNetworkInterface$ClientLoopbackSocketFactory@580e1ef0]:
>   reuse connection 17:08:15.291 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP
>   Connection(37)-127.0.0.1: accepted socket from [127.0.0.1:50861]
>   17:08:15.291 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI
>   RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:17933,org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.LoopbackNetworkInterface$ClientLoopbackSocketFactory@580e1ef0]:
>   create reaper 17:08:15.292 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP
>   Connection(37)-127.0.0.1: (port 49669) op = 80 17:08:15.292 [DEBUG]
>   [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(37)-127.0.0.1: name =
>   "[Ljava.rmi.server.ObjID;", codebase = "" 17:08:15.293 [DEBUG]
>   [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(37)-127.0.0.1: name =
>   "java.rmi.dgc.Lease", codebase = "" 17:08:15.293 [DEBUG]
>   [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(37)-127.0.0.1: name =
>   "java.rmi.dgc.VMID", codebase = "" 17:08:15.293 [DEBUG]
>   [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP Connection(37)-127.0.0.1: name = "[B",
>   codebase = "" 17:08:15.293 [DEBUG] [sun.rmi.loader] RMI TCP
>   Connection(37)-127.0.0.1: name = "java.rmi.server.UID", codebase =
>   ""

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with a query with Room was too long and complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Setup memory allocation for AndroidStudio

1. Click Help > Edit Custom VM Options.
2. Add the below lines

   -Xms1G

   -Xmx2G

   -XX:MaxPermSize=1G

   -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
3. Save and restart AndroidStudio